# NodeJS - Export private key from java keystore file

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, jwt, keystore

I'm implementing JWT bearer token flow on NodeJS and here is the knowledge base which I am trying out,
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_jwt_flow.htm&type=5

You can see a sample java code for constructing JWT bearer token. It extracts private key from the java keystore and signs the JWT header and JWT claims object.

```
      //Load the private key from a keystore
      KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
      keystore.load(new FileInputStream("./path/to/keystore.jks"), "keystorepassword".toCharArray());
      PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey) keystore.getKey("certalias", "privatekeypassword".toCharArray());

      //Sign the JWT Header + "." + JWT Claims Object
      Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
      signature.initSign(privateKey);
      signature.update(token.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
      String signedPayload = Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(signature.sign());
```

I'm trying the same thing on NodeJS by using `node-keytool` to extract the private key and `jwt-js` for token signer. Looks like, `node-keytool` cannot extract private key from keystore. Can you help me out how to implement the above code on NodeJS?

Comment: you might want to try chilkat, but i'm hesitant since it's not open source https://www.example-code.com/nodejs/jks_to_pem.asp

Comment: Were you able to obtain/set a private key password on SFDC, when you created your cert @moustacheman ? i'm having the same problem